# No train reservation

Tags: schengen

Applying for a French visa. My itinerary is Abuja- London- Paris - Amsterdam- Abuja. I plan to fly from London to Paris but take the train from Paris to Amsterdam. So I booked the flight for all except for that leg, I mentioned this is my cover letter detailing my plans for the whole trip. I dont want to buy a refundable train ticket like some people do. Is it better to just include that leg of the trip in my flight booking for the purpose of the Visa application and revert to my plan if Visa is approved or does mentioning that I plan to buy train ticket for that leg suffice.

Comment: I do not have an exact answer to the question, but I gues „it will depend“ - having a ticket will probably be on the safe side. I don‘t see much difference in getting a refundable flight ticket vs. a refundable train ticket, though. By the way: Unless you have specific reason to fly, the train between London and Paris is faster and more convenient.

Comment: Just curious as to why the London transit is planned rather than direct to Paris?

Comment: I'm planning to spend 2 days in London

Comment: I don’t think they will care for a minute about an intra-Schengen train ride. What they are a lot more concerned about is about the applicant leaving the Schengen Area.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to travel from Paris to Amsterdam and for many of those you do not need to buy tickets in advance.
Visa officials know and do understand that.

If you prefer to show a ticket/reservation, look into bus travel. If booked early they can cost as little as €15.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a note that you're going to take the train to cross from Netherlands to France and submit it along with the rest of documentation, so they're confident that you did think of that.

I was adviced to do just that at visa center and did, with success.